# Hibernate Native SQL With Criteria

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, criteria

Подскажите пожалуйста как лучше всего организовать следующее

Был метод:

```
public Set<Word> getAll(Criterion criterion) {
    Criteria criteria = session
        .createCriteria(Word.class,"w")
        .add(criterion);
    return new HashSet<Word>(criteria.list());
}
```

Сейчас же понадобилось реализовать что то такое

```
String strSql = "select w1.id, w1.word_group_id, w1.native_word, w1.description, w1.comment, w1.language, " +
        "  w2.id as tid, w2.word_group_id as tword_group_id, w2.native_word as tnative_word, w2.description as tdescription , w2.comment as tcomment, w2.language as tlanguage " +
        "from (select * " +
        "      from words " +
        "      order by native_word " +
        "      limit 100 offset 100) w1 " +
        "inner join word_translate wt on wt.native_word_id = w1.id " +
        "inner join words w2 on w2.id = wt.translate_word_id";
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(strSql);
```

но как "красиво" добавить `Criterion`? Менять сигнатуру метода? Или же добывать из `Criterion` и вставлять во `where`?